# Build action. Documentation error, bug, or me?

Tags: screeps

Is this a bug or incorrect documentation, or am I just misreading?

According to the documentation, one WORK part "constructs a structure for 1 energy per tick."

But if you actually watch, at least in the tutorial, each tick consumes 5 energy, and increments the Progress of the construction by 5.

Note: If the creep has less than 5 energy, it will use the remaining energy and increment Progress by that amount. If the construction is within 5 of completion, it only uses the amount of energy necessary to complete.

Comment: a standard spawn can spawn creeps up to 5 parts in length; are you sure you don't have a creep that is 5 work parts?

Comment: @AndrewCounts His question is about building structures, not about building the creep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same thing, seems either a documentation typo or bug. My bet would be a documentation typo, since otherwise construction would take way too long to be feasible.

Comment: Yep. Probably doc typo, we need @artch to clarify this.